# FileWriter false overwrites file from string A to Z BUT leaves only string Z; how do I keep string A-Z?

Tags: java, append, filewriter

So I have the following code within my program. What I'm trying to do is print the variables I have declared in main of program to a csv file. I want to replace what is already in the csv file (the file exists before we get to this portion of code so all we have to do is replace what is already there). Now, I tried (myFoo, false) but what happens is that the program iterates through A-Z and leaves only Z in the csv file. I want it to write everything from A-Z in the csv file and not just what is at Z.

My code:

```
     for(int t=0; t<superArray.size(); t++) {

         String temp = superArray.get(t).character;
         int temp2 = superArray.get(t).quantity;
         int temp3 = superArray.get(t).width;
         String temp4 = superArray.get(t).color;
         int temp5 = superArray.get(t).height;

         String eol = System.getProperty("line.separator");

         String line=temp+","+temp2+","+temp3+","+temp4+","+temp5 + eol;


         File myFoo = new File("Letters.csv");
         FileWriter fooWriter = new FileWriter(myFoo, true); 


         fooWriter.write(line);
         fooWriter.close();
```

The next thing I thought of trying.. I thought maybe I could do (myFoo, true) and right before I write to the file, I would clear out the original content of the csv file. So it would append to an empty csv file.

```
         File myFoo = new File("Letter_Inventory.csv");
         myFoo.createNewFile();
         FileWriter fooWriter = new FileWriter(myFoo, true);
```

The logic sounds good to me, but that obviously didn't work so I'm here now. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're re-opening and closing the file with each iteration of the for loop! This will over-write anything that was written to the file from the previous iterations of the loop. The solution is: don't do that. Open the file *once* and do so **before** the for loop.

Change

```
for(int t=0; t<superArray.size(); t++) {

     // ....etc....
     String line=temp+","+temp2+","+temp3+","+temp4+","+temp5 + eol;

     File myFoo = new File("Letters.csv");
     FileWriter fooWriter = new FileWriter(myFoo, true); 


     fooWriter.write(line);
     fooWriter.close();
}
```

to this

```
// file created *before* the for loop
File myFoo = new File("Letters.csv");
FileWriter fooWriter = new FileWriter(myFoo, true); 

for(int t=0; t<superArray.size(); t++) {

     // .... etc ....
     String line=temp+","+temp2+","+temp3+","+temp4+","+temp5 + eol;
     fooWriter.write(line); // line written inside for loop

}

// this should be in the finally block.
fooWriter.close();
```

Comment: That did it. I just had to change true to false so it would overwrite instead of append. Thanks!